# How to hide and show android dialog programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

When user clicks *create new game* I show him a dialog. I'm trying to  to hide Dialog when button event is 'ACTION_DOWN' and show it back when event is 'ACTION_UP'.

As you can see in the code below what I'm trying to do is to hide Dialog when user presses eye button and when he/she releases it show it back again. I tried to play around with transparency but only made background invisible, not all elements.

```java
    private void dialogNewGame(final Context context) {
        final Dialog filterDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.NewGameDialogStyle);
        filterDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dailog_new_game);
        filterDialog.setCancelable(true);
        filterDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        filterDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        ImageButton eyeButton = filterDialog.findViewById(R.id.eye);
        eyeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    filterDialog.dismiss();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    dialogNewGame(context);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I get that hide/show functionality on button press/release?

Comment: Hello Kyrylo, have you had a chance to read about how android dialogs work? [here's the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes I did and I didn't find my answer there that's why I'm here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `hide()` and `show()` will change the visibility of the dialog. However, if the application closes while the `Dialog` is **hidden** a window leak error will occur. You will need to correctly `dismis()` the dialog in the appropriate end-of-lifecycle methods like `onDestroy()`.

```
private Dialog filterDialog;

private void dialogNewGame(final Context context) {
    filterDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.NewGameDialogStyle);
    filterDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dailog_new_game);
    filterDialog.setCancelable(true);
    filterDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    filterDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    ImageButton eyeButton = filterDialog.findViewById(R.id.eye);
    eyeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                filterDialog.hide();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                dialogNewGame(context); //Showing dialog
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

//Handle dismiss
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (filterDialog != null)
        filterDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: appreciate, perfect, works as a charm, I will accept in a few minutes.